# If Or Formula Gets Pasted Into Another Field

Tags: worksheet-function

I have three columns A B C.

I want to put the data in column C that exists in either column A or B. Only one column in A or B will have data.

Examples:

Data in Column A: 123456789

Data in Column B:

Data That Goes in Column C: 123456789

Data in Column A:

Data in Column B: 987654321

Data That Goes in Column C: 987654321

Thank you for that last answer.

I need slight variation on that:

I want to put text in column C based on data that exists in either column A or B. Only one column in A or B will have data. If data is in column A - then text in column C will always be "UPC". If data is in column B - then text in column C will always be "EAN". Column C will carry this formula, columns A & B have formulas that pull data from another tab.

Examples:

Data in Column A: 123456789

Data in Column B:

Data That Goes in Column C: UPC

Data in Column A:

Data in Column B: 987654321

Data That Goes in Column C: "EAN"

Comment: Using the basic simple formula =A2 & B2 gives the desired results since only one column or the other will contain data. But I was thinking of a more intelligent way in terms of validating if A contains data use that, if B contains data use that.

Comment: Looks like I will need another variation on this issue:

I have three columns A B C.

I want to put certain data in column C based on which column A or B has data contained in it. Only one column in A or B will have data.

Examples:

Data in Column A: 123456789

Data in Column B:

Data That Goes in Column C: UPC

Data in Column A:

Data in Column B: 987654321

Data That Goes in Column C: EAN

Comment: Please dont provide new information in comments, but edit your question. How should Excel (we) know when to use EAN / UPC???

Answer (score 2):

Seem like a simple `IF()` statement with `ISBLANK()` is what you need.

Check if your A value is blank, if not, then use it's value. If so, then check if your B value is blank, if not, then use it's value.

If both criteria comes out to be blank, just use an empty string (this lets you prepopulate a large range and have it appear blank until the data goes in).

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1)=FALSE, A1,IF(ISBLANK(B1)=FALSE, B1,""))
```

[image]

One caveat: This assumes the blank cells are actually empty.  If the empty cells aren't actually empty (e.g., you're using a formula to display either a value or a blank cell in columns A and B), ISBLANK won't work.

---

If you are not *pre-populating* the C column with your formula, then an easier approach is to simply use

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1), B1, A1)
```

If you were to pre-populate with this formula, then in conditions where both the A & B columns are blank the formula would return `0`.

Comment: That formula seemed to work fine (even though A & B do have formulas in the carrying over data from another tab).

=IF(ISBLANK(A1), B1, A1)